# Visual Studio doen't show all constructors for Rfc2898DeriveBytes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cryptoapi

I am using Rfc2898DeriveBytes class for hashing passwords. And I want to use constructor which changes hashing function ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2)), but Visual studio is saying that constructor doesn't exist and only shows constructors with three parameters.

Previously I was using the version with three parameters which worked.

```
new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, m_iterations);
```

This works fine.

```
new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(pass, salt, m_iterations, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

This should work, but doesn't

Comment: Are you are set to use 4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These overloads were added in .NET 4.7.2, .NET Core 2.0, and .NET Standard 2.1 (preview) - you can check this by using the .NET version selector in the top left.

Make sure your project is targeting one of these versions, or higher.